# Search Array for object with same name and remove

Tags: angular, typescript

The user can upload images, therefore I created an input type file.

Each time the user chooses a file, this function is executed:

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList, event: string) {
    const firstFile = files.item(0);
    this.files.push({ file: firstFile, name: event});
}
```

Now if the user changes his input again, (let's assume there's only one input field) there will be two files inside of `this.files` *for one field*.

`Name` stores the name of the input field, **hence I should be able to filter `this.array`, search for name duplicates and if so, remove them.**

But how can I do so?

Comment: use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of array for `this.files`

Comment: @ysf How do I search a set with objects `{ file: firstFile, name: event}` for only its name?